# How can I deploy multiple versions of an MFP 8 Adapter?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

In MFP 8, is there a facility or convention for deploying multiple versions of an adapter on one server?

For example, on my dev server, I want both version 0.2 and version 0.3 of my adapter running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no versioning on Adapters. You may open a feature request with MobileFirst Platform Foundation if this is a needed feature for your development:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=submitRfe